# Use "each nth point" with \addplot3

Tags: pgfplots, 3d

I would like to use `each nth point` in combination with `\addplot3` to plot every tenth data-point for both the x-axis and y-axis, but whatever I try, pgfplots just ignores it and uses all the data points that are provided in the table.

```tex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}

\pgfplotstableread{
    0.  0.  0.
    0.  0.33    0.04
    0.  0.67    0.30
    0.  1.  1.
    0.33    0.  0.11
    0.33    0.33    0.15
    0.33    0.67    0.41
    0.33    1.  1.11
    0.67    0.  0.44
    0.67    0.33    0.48
    0.67    0.67    0.74
    0.67    1.  1.44
    1.  0.  1.
    1.  0.33    1.03
    1.  0.67    1.30
    1.  1.  2.
}\datatable

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \pgfplotsset{filter discard warning=false, unbounded coords=discard}
        \begin{groupplot}[group style = {group size = 1 by 1}, each nth point*={1}{2}, each nth point*={2}{2}]
            \nextgroupplot
            \addplot3[surf, mesh/rows=4, mesh/ordering=y varies, shader=flat] table {\datatable};
        \end{groupplot}
        
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

It does not give any errors, but it still plots the whole table instead of only a part of it. I suspect I need to tell pgfplots which data to apply this to, something like `each nth point*={table}{1}{10}`, but I'm not sure exactly how to do so. How can this be fixed?

Comment: Can't check, because you have not added a test data file for us to check, but, have you tried to add the `each nth point` to the `addplot3` options? (I know it works on 2D graphs, never tried on 3D ones).

Comment: @Rmano I tried that, but it gives the same result (no error, no skipping). I have added some test data to the post.